# Missing time format when using momentJS to convert unix timestamp into date and time

Tags: angularjs, datetime, momentjs, angular-moment

When I save the following string to the server:

```
moment(serverTime).format('(dddd) DD/MMM/YYYY, HH:mm:ss (Z)')
```

I get `"(Sunday) 26/Jun/2016, 00:00:00 (+02:00)"` saved. It seems that it won't do the time properly..

If I just save the `serverTime` as an integer on the server and convert it via angular-moment:

```
<div>{{event.datetime | amDateFormat:'(dddd) DD/MMM/YYYY, HH:mm:ss'}}</div>
```

I get `Sunday) 26/Jun/2016, 12:48:02 (+02:00)` displayed...

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please confirm if event.datetime is a number. I doubt it is already a formatted string from server..

Comment: I think you got something.. It seems to be that the serverTime is an object.. and once I save that object to the server it stores it as a number...

Comment: It is almost certainly the case that your input value is not what you think it is. Are you receiving a warning in the console that says 'moment construction falls back to JS Date'?